# Detected access of super global var $_SERVER, probably needs manual inspection and Missing wp_unslash() before sanitization

Tags: php, wordpress, phpsniff

I use this coding standard package to check my code: https://github.com/inpsyde/php-coding-standards

But whenever I run php, I get these error:

```
 13 | WARNING | Detected access of super global var $_SERVER, probably needs manual inspection.
    |         | (WordPress.VIP.SuperGlobalInputUsage.AccessDetected)
 14 | WARNING | Detected access of super global var $_SERVER, probably needs manual inspection.
    |         | (WordPress.VIP.SuperGlobalInputUsage.AccessDetected)
 14 | ERROR   | Missing wp_unslash() before sanitization. (WordPress.VIP.ValidatedSanitizedInput.MissingUnslash)
```

Here is the class:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Dummy;

class Dummy
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->route();
    }

    public function route(): string
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            $request = esc_url_raw($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            if ($request === "/users") {
                return PLUGIN_PATH . '/src/page/UserPage.php';
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

- Is there a way to use $_SERVER without getting these warnings?
- For the wp_unslash(), I don't what to remove slashes, is there a way to correct this without suppressing the Error in ?

Thanks in advance.